# CSS to remove the hyperlink on a header of the page

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS, I am working on an application where I want to remove/hide the hyperlink from the header of the webpage. I clicked on the "inspect element" on the header and found the below code-

```
<a class="app-header-horizontal-navbar__text" data-bind="text: link.text, attr: {
                        title: link.text,
                        href: link.url,
                        'aria-label': link.text
                    }" title="Careers &amp; MyHR" href="https://oracle.fa.ocs.oraclecloud.com/hcmUI/CandidateExperience/en/sites/CX_1" aria-label="Careers &amp; MyHR">Careers &amp; MyHR</a>
```

I want to apply CSS so that I can remove the hyperlink when we click on "Careers & My HR" on the page. I tried the below but it didnt work and the page is the same:

```
.app-header-horizontal-navbar__text .input-row [data-qa="Careers &amp; MyHR"]  {     display: none;
}.app-header-horizontal-navbar__text .input-row label[for^="Careers &amp; MyHR-"]   {
     display: none;
}
 
.candidate-links {
display: block;
margin: 60px auto 0;
visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: The classnames in your CSS don't seem to match your HTML at all.  Try `.app-header-horizontal-navbar__text {display: none}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The class name you given for the  element not matching with the CSS style definition.

.app-header-horizontal-navbar__text - this is the className

Try this CSS code:

```
.app-header-horizontal-navbar__text {
       pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or if you want to remove/hide entire element use this:

```
.app-header-horizontal-navbar__text {
    display: block;
    margin: 60px auto 0;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, you need to use `:active`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).